# Live Preview not showing content, Craft 3

Tags: craft3, live-preview, preview

I use the same templates for live preview as for the front end. Until a recent change in Craft 3, they worked fine for live preview, then they stopped showing most fields.

I use a lot of includes to build pages, for example, I send the id of an entry to a separate template to display a Matrix field. I just pass **entry.id**.

Answer (score 1):

According to Brandon, in live preview, you can no longer use **entry.id**, you have to use **entry.sourceId** to get the current draft.

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/5087#issuecomment-541243645